# Problem When embedding JSON Object inside another object by DBRef

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass, dbref

I wrote the code to try DBRef Concept:

The Students Collections has:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Omar",
  "LastName": "Ali",
  "IsFired": true,
  "FacultyID":
    {
      "$ref": "Faculty",
      "$id": "633d5fca2bed487dd7eb4e11",
      "$db": "FacultySystemV2"
    },
  "CoursesList": [
    {
      "CourseID": {
        "$oid": "633d5fd62bed487dd7eb4e14"
      },
      "Grade": 95
    },
    {
      "CourseID": {
        "$oid": "633d602c2bed487dd7eb4e15"
      },
      "Grade": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

The Faculty Collections has:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('633d5fca2bed487dd7eb4e11')
  "FacultyName": "Alex University",
  "Address": "Alex City"
}
```

Unfortunately, it can't recognize the $id or $ref inside the DPRef

```
var stds6 = db.Students.findOne({"FirstName": "Omar"})
db[stds6.FacultyID.$ref].findOne({"_id": (stds6.FacultyID.$id)})
```

Even if I write:

stds6.FacultyID.$ref
or

stds6.FacultyID.$id
I get notinge Faculty Collections has:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('633d5fca2bed487dd7eb4e11')
  "FacultyName": "Alex University",
  "Address": "Alex City"
}
```

Unfortunately, it can't recognize the $id or $ref inside the DPRef

```
var stds6 = db.Students.findOne({"FirstName": "Omar"})
db[stds6.FacultyID.$ref].findOne({"_id": (stds6.FacultyID.$id)})
```

Even if I write:

```
stds6.FacultyID.$ref
```

or

```
stds6.FacultyID.$id
```

I get noting

Comment: What does `console.log(stds6)` show.

Comment: It gives the whole JSON Object "The first code above"

Comment: What driver are you using?  Driver support is noted [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#driver-support-for-dbrefs)

Comment: @user20042973 I am not quite sure, but I think it's node JS. Do you know how to check?